# Does bcp utility support Token based Authentication? If yes, I would like to know the process and which version of bcp to be used

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, access-token, bcp

I am trying to push data available in bcp files to tables in Azure SQL DB using Managed Identity Authentication method. I want to know if this is possible to authenticate using Access Token.

I am inside a 'System Assigned Managed Identity' enabled VM, and using a PowerShell script, I am able to execute this BCP file using SQL Server Auth and MFA based Auth.

But my main goal is to connect using the Managed Identity Auth (from Azure VM). I am able to retrieve the access token, but I would like to know how to use this token to login to the DB and run the bcp command successfully.

---

**Note:** Using Managed Identity Authentication, I am able to connect and query the Azure SQL Database from the Azure VM using *Invoke-SqlCmd* command, but bcp utility is not working.

Comment: No, The new bcp supports Microsoft Entra authentication, including multifactor authentication (MFA) support for Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Hi @PratikLad. Thank you for your answer. Yes, I can run bcp successfully using the Microsoft Entra Auth with MFA. But I would like to know how to run bcp using the System assigned Managed Identity based Authentication. Can you please let me know about that?

Comment: AFAIK there is no support for System assigned Managed Identity based Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Using an Access Token stored in a variable for direct authentication and running BCP commands against an Azure SQL Database using Managed Identity Authentication is not a supported method.

Managed Identity Authentication is typically used for authenticating applications and services running in Azure to access Azure resources securely without the need for storing credentials.

AS per [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#version-information)

> The new **bcp** supports Microsoft Entra authentication, including multifactor authentication (MFA) support for Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics.

Comment: Yes I am trying to connect to the Azure SQL Database from an Azure VM which has System Assigned Managed Identity enabled.

Also, I came across this Microsoft document where it says the latest version of bcp is able to perform Token based Authentication. Could you please guide me on how to perform this, please?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connecting-with-bcp?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=a%20data%20file.-,%2DG,-This%20switch%20is